# Compile OpenCV 2.4.3-rc with gstreamer on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, opencv, compilation, gstreamer, ip-camera

I am able to compile OpenCV on my Mac without gstreamer.

The problem is, gstreamer doesn't seem to be picked up by `cmake`, even though I have the following libraries installed via Macports:

```
    ffmpeg-devel                   @20121205       multimedia/ffmpeg-devel
    ...
    gst-ffmpeg                     @0.10.13        gnome/gst-ffmpeg
    gst-plugins-bad                @0.10.23        gnome/gst-plugins-bad
    gst-plugins-base               @0.10.36        gnome/gst-plugins-base
    gst-plugins-gl                 @0.10.3         gnome/gst-plugins-gl
    gst-plugins-good               @0.10.31        gnome/gst-plugins-good
    gst-plugins-math               @0.1.0          science/gst-plugins-math
    gstreamer                      @0.10.36        gnome/gstreamer
```

My cmake generate log looks like this (most omitted):

```
    --   Video I/O:
    --     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    --     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.1.3)
    --     FFMPEG:                      YES
    --       codec:                     YES (ver Unknown)
    --       format:                    YES (ver Unknown)
    --       util:                      YES (ver Unknown)
    --       swscale:                   YES (ver Unknown)
    --       gentoo-style:              YES
    --     OpenNI:                      NO
    --     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    --     PvAPI:                       NO
    --     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    --     QuickTime:                   NO
    --     QTKit:                       YES
```

As you can see, `gstreamer` doesn't exist on the generated logs.

I am trying to use OpenCV for an Apexis IP Camera, which serves the video feed via HTTP.  With Gstreamer, I am able to build on Ubuntu 12.10 Server edition---and the IP Camera works---but I would prefer to be able to have a GUI session on my Mac.

Any insights are welcome.

Comment: You might need to configure cmake to look at the pkgconfig, include, and lib paths for macports installed libraries.

Comment: @yiding How would I do that?

Comment: On second check, I just saw `OCV_OPTION(WITH_GSTREAMER      "Include Gstreamer support"                   ON   IF (UNIX AND NOT APPLE AND NOT ANDROID) )` in my `CMakeLists.txt`.  Maybe it was blacklisted. Gonna give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @yiding, I found the issue.

OpenCV blacklisted gstreamer on the Mac for some reason.  I was able to unblacklist it by simply changing the cmake configurations (`CMakeLists.txt`).

Change

```
OCV_OPTION(WITH_GSTREAMER "Include Gstreamer support" ON IF (UNIX AND NOT APPLE AND NOT ANDROID) )
```

to

```
OCV_OPTION(WITH_GSTREAMER "Include Gstreamer support" ON IF (UNIX AND NOT ANDROID) )
```

Then, I reinstalled both `ffmpeg` and `gstreamer` and all dependencies, and recompiled with `make -j8`.  `sudo make install`.  That was it.

Now I have IP Camera streaming to my Mac using OpenCV!

*Edit*: For context, this is OpenCV 2.4.3-rc and Mac OS X 10.8.

Comment: I can confirm that with later versions of OpenCV, this is not an issue. Gstreamer is auto-compiled with it on Mac OS.